# Definition issue JPA with 3 tables and composite primary keys

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, composite-primary-key

I have three jpa-defined tables: 'continent', 'country', and 'region'.
They have whole part relations, ie. a country cannot exist without a continent.
Therefore I modeled the classes for continent and country and the spring generated ddl is fine, everything works:

```
@Entity
public class Continent {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Short id;
//[..]
}

@Entity
public class Country implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6825504967607930373L;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne 
    @JoinColumn(name="continent_id")
    private Continent continent;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Short id;
//[..]
}
```

But if I add Region, I don't know how to define the relation without hibernate giving me an error during initialization (see below).

```
@Entity
public class Region {

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumns({
//      @JoinColumn(name="continent_id"),
        @JoinColumn(name="country_id")
    })
    private Country country;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    Short id;

//[..]
}
```

This definition gives me the error

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Foreign key (FK_otariwhls1krq0bo780jtvbqn:region [country_id])) must have same number of columns as the referenced primary key (country [id,continent_id])
at org.hibernate.mapping.ForeignKey.alignColumns(ForeignKey.java:110)
```

but if I remove the // from the continent_id join column i get this error instead:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: A Foreign key refering com...Country from com...bo.Region has the wrong number of column. should be 1
at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.TableBinder.bindFk(TableBinder.java:502)
```

What am I doing wrong? I'm using Hibernate 4.3.11 final on mysql in a Springboot 1.3 environment.

Answer (score 0):

Use only the `@JoinColumn(name="country_id")` wihtout `@JoinColumns` (note the plural) and remove the `@Id` from the `Region.country` property.

Comment: This still gives the error "Foreign key (FK_otariwhls1krq0bo780jtvbqn:region [country_id])) must have same number of columns as the referenced primary key (country [id,continent_id])" when country is only defined as "@ManyToOne  @JoinColumn(name="country_id") private Country country;"

Comment: Also remove from the `Country.continent` the `@Id` annotation.

Comment: This makes the error go away, but I don't have the primary key part on continent_id anymore. "desc country" on the database returns this resultset: id smallint(6) NO PRI  auto_increment /  name varchar(255) YES / continent_id smallint(6) YES MUL Before removing the @Id from Country it defined a composite primary key.

Comment: If you want to work with a primary key over multiple columns (i.e composite primary key), you could work with an Embedded Key. Take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22002739/hibernate-jpa-manytoone-composite-key

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a try, i've seen the EmbeddedId annotations before but thought that this maybe doesn't work since I have to define two composites, one for continent/country and one ternary for continent/country/region the join column definition seemd more natural to me